# How can I avoid a small space between my <input> and <span> elements?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<input style="width: 20px" data-ng-model="row.number" type="text" />
<span style="width: 20px">-</span>
```

How can I avoid the small space between the `<input>` and `<span>`, and how can I center the "-" in the span.

I need a solution other than to put all on one line as my IDE reformats to multiple lines.

Comment: Be aware that `span` are inline elements by default, so they ignore `width` property. You can change that using, for example,  `display:inline-block`

Comment: centering in span is not meaningful. why don't you use div tag to center the - symbol.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `span` is an `inline` level element, which respects the whitespace in the markup.

There are multiple ways to remove this, one is simply removing the space within the markup:

```
<input style="width: 20px" data-ng-model="row.number" type="text" /><span style="width: 20px">-</span>
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF77g/)

---

Another way is setting the parent element to `font-size:0px`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7t9k/)

---

Another is setting negative margins in order to displace the whitespace. `span { margin: -4px; }`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kxd8/)

Comment: I'm sorry but doing this and my line would be a couple of hundred characters long.

Comment: If I set the font-size to zero then what about the size of my characters?

Comment: @Melina See the example, it is somewhat of a hack. You set the parent to `font-size:0px`, then set the child to whatever you want. In the example above I reset it to `font-size:16px` which is the default.

Comment: Small note: use `font-size:0` instead of `font-size:0px`. Otherwise, I agree - excellent suggestions.

Comment: The first solution is good. `margin: 4px` is not quite recommended because it differs on every browser. and also giving `font-size: 0px` is not recommended because we need to apply the font size again to the child elements which in many cases we don't know the default font-size(_good if we are using less_).

Comment: @Mr_Green Agreed - removing the whitespace in the markup is the best, and most optimal solution. The rest are cheap hacks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- HTML comments between elements:

  ```
  <div><!--
      --><input style="width: 20px" data-ng-model="row.number" type="text" /><!--
      --><span style="width: 20px">-</span><!--
  --></div>
  ```
- Closing `>` to the next line:

  ```
  <div
      ><input style="width: 20px" data-ng-model="row.number" type="text"
      /><span style="width: 20px">-</span
  ></div>
  ```
- `font-size:0` on parent (reset it on children if necessary)
- `float:left` (remember to clear it adding an element with `clear:both` after floating elements)
- In a far future, we will be able to use `text-space-collapse: trim-inner`. Be aware that it isn't currently supported, and the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-4/#white-space-collapsing) is a draft not ready for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the join and break technique:

```
<input style='width:20px;' data-ng-model='row.number' type='text' /><span
style='width:20px;'>-</span>
```

Notice the line breaks after the tag opens.  This is a technique to balance having long lines versus spurious whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

put the input and the span on the same line in your html

Comment: Well I am not sure that's possible. I have a lot of elements and I just showed two. The line would be very long.

Comment: Who cares how long the line is in the source?

Comment: put the line breaks elsewhere in your html see the answer by bishop.

Answer (score 0):

You should give same css properties to both the input element and the span element.

```
input,span{
    float: left; /* helpful to remove the gap */
    line-height: 15px;  /* centering by giving the value of height */
    height: 15px;    /* same height to both the elements */
}
span{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 0px; /* removing left border to decrease the gap */
}
```

In the above stylings, I am giving border to the span element because the input has border by default.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfd2J/)

### or else

You can also use `display: table-cell` and do something like this:

```
input, span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input {
    outline: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body { /* or parent element */
    display: table;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfd2J/1/)